# Troubelshooting raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes")

Tags: python, rest, web

I have an error raised by the following piece of code

```
    def __to_canonical_querystring_post(self, params):
    canonical_querystring = ""
    # parameters have to be sorted alphabetically for the signing part
    for param_key, param_value in sorted(params.items()):
        if canonical_querystring != "":
            canonical_querystring += "&"
        canonical_querystring += param_key + "=" + urllib.parse.quote(param_value)
    return canonical_querystring
```

The params are 
 Make_Payment_params = {
    "debitAccountNumber": 12003189487,
    "creditAccountNumber": 12065812627,
    "amount": 100,
    "requestedExecutionDate": "2019-03-09"
}

and the error is   raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes")
TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The argument to `urllib.parse.quote` must be a string, but your code sometimes passes integers instead. Changing the call to something like `urllib.parse.quote(str(param_value))` should fix the problem.